# Java FreeTTS: The package com.sun.speech is not accessible

Tags: java, import, text-to-speech, importerror, freetts

I tried to make a tts code but i faild at the very beginning. The .jars are downloaded and in my lib, but i can`t import them into my code. it only shows: "The package com.sun.speech is not accessible"
Did that happen to anyone else and does anyone know how to resolve this?

Idk if this helps, but im using eclipse, i have a module-info.java and i added: "requires jdk.httpserver;"
but that doesnt help

import com.sun.speech.freetts.Voice;
import com.sun.speech.freetts.VoiceManager;

and thats where i failed, the first 2 lines of code. I never had a problem with importing stuff and it also works if i imoprt other things in the same class